# Visual Cues in a wave file

Tags: pro-tools, logic

Is there a way to put visual cues in a wave/audio file? I'm trying to essentially find a way to 'draw' on an audio file so that it makes it easier to work with in a video game engine for syncing purposes.

Is it possible to create markers in the wave file that show outside of the DAW?

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to use the marker system already present in Broadcast Wav. The issue is more getting your other software to read them, possible though if the software is bespoke.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Pro Tools user but this link offers some good information: http://bleepsandpops.com/post/37792760450/adding-cue-points-to-wav-files-in-c

The above link points to a page describing how to insert cue points into a wav file thru c programming.